# MFC Window toolbar creation fails with no error message

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to dynamically create a toolbar for my MFC application. I have to following approach for this task. However, the toolbar doesn't show up in my window and I get no error message...

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) {
  // ...
  CToolBar menubar;
  if(!menubar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_LIST, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC)) {
    return -1;
  }

  TBBUTTON buttons[5] = {
    { -1, ID_TOOLBAR_FILE, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE | BTNS_DROPDOWN, { 0 }, 0, (INT_PTR)L"File" },
    { -1, ID_TOOLBAR_EDIT, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE | BTNS_DROPDOWN, { 0 }, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Edit" },
    { -1, ID_TOOLBAR_VIEW, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE | BTNS_DROPDOWN, { 0 }, 0, (INT_PTR)L"View" },
    { -1, ID_TOOLBAR_LAYOUT, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE | BTNS_DROPDOWN, { 0 }, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Layout" },
    { -1, ID_TOOLBAR_HELP, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE | BTNS_DROPDOWN, { 0 }, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Help" }
  };


  ::SendMessage(menubar.GetSafeHwnd(), TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
  ::SendMessage(menubar.GetSafeHwnd(), TB_ADDBUTTONS, (WPARAM)5, (LPARAM)&buttons);

  ::SendMessage(menubar.GetSafeHwnd(), TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
  ::ShowWindow(menubar.GetSafeHwnd(), SW_SHOW);
}
```

This will not display my toolbar. Why is this happening?

Comment: The last member of TBBUTTON is a string index, which looks like it needs to be added using TB_ADDSTRING.  Have you looked at CreateToolbarEx?

Comment: Check out the source for `GetSafeHwnd()`, this function is especially tailored to be called with a null `this` pointer, IIRC. In your case though, it can't possibly be null. However, the window handle could be NULL! In order to have that checked, use `menubar.SendMessage()` instead, which properly asserts that the pointer is set. Also, of course make sure that you do compile with debugging enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that declaring the toolbar as class member solves the problem. So here is what I did:

```
class CMainFrame : public CFramWnd {
protected:
  CToolBar m_wndToolBar;
  // ...
}
```

And the rest of the code is practically unchanged. I am still not sure why it works this way.

Comment: An object with automatic storage duration gets destroyed, when it leaves the scope where it is defined. In other words, when `OnCreate` returns, your `menubar` object is destroyed, and its destructor destroys the toolbar control along the way. Making it a class member ties the toolbar control's lifetime to that of the main frame window.

Comment: Great explanation. I knew that too but I didn't make a connection. Thank you!